# React Router doesn't change the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I setup React Router but it doesn't work.

I see that URL has changed, I see it in the history of browser. But the page doesn't change.

I want to go to other component which should look like a separate page (not related to the old page, from where I go).

How can I do that?

```
render() {
  return (
    <Link to={`/details/${this.props.movie.id}`}>
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.movie.title}</p>
        <div>
         <img 
            src={IMG_URL + this.props.movie.poster_path} 
            className='preview'
            alt={this.props.movie.overview}/>
        </div>

        <Route path='/details/:number' component={MovieDetails}/>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Main />
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes should be declared at a higher level, not as a child of a `Link`

For example in index.js

```
 <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/details/:number" component={MovieDetails} />
    </div>
 </Router>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! 
Should all routes be declared in index.js? Right?
Maybe are there some other solutions? Store them in the independent file and load in index.js, or smth? Maybe store paths in constants?
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend splitting routes into their own file and just included them in index.js